# Custom editor for tags in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, tags, backbone-model

I'm using [backbone forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) and have been creating customising editors to meet my needs.

I've now moved onto wanting to edit tags for a model and before I go ahead and implement my own, I was wondering if there was already a custom editor capable of this?

For example, the model could have a tags field stored as a string:

```
@model.tags # = 'this, and, that, foo, bar')
```

I want to define my backbone form as follows:

```
class CPP.Models.Event extends Backbone.Model
  # Definitions (url etc)
  ...

  # Form Schema
  schema:
    tags:
      type: "TagEditor"
      url: "/someurl"
```

This would then result in an editor with the following fields:

- **Text Field** - For adding tags, autocompleted with values loaded from url (sending through existing tags so as to avoid duplicates)
- **Tags Container** - Contains all the tags in their own divs (I would then style these)

When I add a new tag by pressing enter it would add the tag to the tag container and then when I later read from the editor, it would condense the tag container/tags back into a comma separated list.

Hopefully this makes sense, I'm almost sure I've seen someone doing this in a github repo somewhere but I've been searching for a good hour through google and my history and I can't find it anywhere.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the file on github I was looking for at https://github.com/jumski/backbone-widgets/blob/master/src/views/tag_editor.js.coffee